# Residue of $\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(iz)}$ at $-n\pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I would like to calculate the residue of $$\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(iz)} \quad \text{at} \quad -n\pi i.$$ I know that this is a first order pole and I already tried it with power series,
but I'm not able to get the result from the solutions, which is $(-1)^n$

Also is there a generalized way to calculate the residue of such fractions?

Comment: [Those are simple poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula $$\text{Res}_{z=z_0} f=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0) f(z).$$ In this case, we can use the Taylor series of $\sin iz$ to get that \begin{align*}
&\lim_{z\rightarrow -n\pi i}(z+n\pi i)\frac{e^z}{\sin iz}\\
&=\lim_{z\rightarrow -n\pi i}(z+n\pi i)\frac{e^z}{\sin (n\pi )+i\cos {n\pi }(z+n\pi i)+\cdots}\\
&=\frac{e^{-n\pi i}}{i\cos n\pi}=-i,
\end{align*} since $\sin{n\pi}=0$ and $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$\lim_{z\to -n\pi i} (z+n\pi i)\frac{e^z}{\sin iz}$$
Use L'Hospital to find the limit.
Answer comes $-i$ instead of $(-1)^n$.

Comment: It looks like $-i$ instead of $(-1)^n$ as the OP implies.

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: I really don't know why it says $(-1)^n$... Using L'Hopital, I get the same result as you. Thanks for the quick reply.